# Handling onmouseover | onmouseout

Tags: javascript

I have got a HTML-list holding a lot of items containing strings ("xyz"). When the user hovers over an item of the list, a separated area that should display the description of the item is created.

Every item calls a function on 
    `Object.onmouseover = MyFunction`
that will show the description and a function on
    `Object.onmouseout = MyFunction`
that will hide the description.

The problem is that there is not enough space on the website to have an area that is only holding the description and the area of the description always has a different size.

If the user hovers fast over the list, some descriptions show but do not hide again. Because the description is shown in front of some of the items of the list, the created area now blocks some of the items and makes them unusable (you can not hover/click them anymore).

Making this list unusable has a high impact for the user performance and most of the times forces the user to reload the website and redo an approximately 5-10 minute procedure.

So, is there any way to show and hide the description without using 
    `Object.onmouseover = MyFunction`
and
    `Object.onmouseout = MyFunction`
to call the functions?

Best regards

Comment: I suggest to use in your case css (`:hover`). What happens in `MyFunction` to cause size changes?

Answer (score 0):

Add the HTML and hide it with CSS `display: none;`

As said by RajmondX you could use the CSS selector of `:hover {dispay: block/inline-block/flex;}` when going over the always visible item.

For example, HTML looks like this:

```
<nav>
   <ul>
      <li>
        ...
      </li>
   </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS looks like this:

```
ul {
  display: none;
}
```

`ul` would have your diffrent descriptions, then you could add CSS like this:

```
ul {
  display: none;
}

nav:hover ul {
  display: block;
}
```

This way you would see your ul element when hovering over it. (But it would be clicking on mobile/tablet)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! In my case I use `Object.insertBefore` and `Object.removeChild` to show and hide the description area. Unfortunately it does not matter which method I use, because the error occurs if you hover fast (on porpuse or not)  over multiple items. So, the actual problem is, that `Object.onmouseout` sometimes is not called.

I am basically looking for another way to call the functions, not change the hide/show functions, because they do not cause any issues.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure how you could fix that but performance wise is it not interesting to always add and remove your element to the DOM tree structure. It'd be better to add them once when the page loads and then hide visually hide them. Only show them on hovering. If you really want to go further with your current solution then I cannot be of any help.